# Excel VBA - calculating mean and standard dev based on whether checkbox is enabled

Tags: excel, checkbox, vba

From rows 5 to 25, I have 2013 data in column C and 2014 data in column D. In column E, I have checkboxes in each row that is linked to the cell it's located in. I use below code to calculate the averages  of the data in columns C and D in row 26, but only including rows which has a true (enabled) checkbox next to it. So far so good.

Now, my problem is, I would like to extend this code to also calculate the mean in row 27 and the standard deviation in row 28, for both 2013 and 2014 (i.e. columns C and D respectively). I'm not really sure how to do this - can you please help me solve this problem? Thanks for your help!

```
mean13 = 0
mean14 = 0
inc = 0

For Each c In ActiveSheet.Range("E5:E26").Cells

If c.Row <> 26 Then

    If c = "True" Then

    mean13 = mean13 + Cells(c.Row, c.Column - 2).Value
    mean14 = mean14 + Cells(c.Row, c.Column - 1).Value
    inc = inc + 1

    End If

ElseIf c.Row = 26 Then

Cells(26, c.Column - 2).Value = mean13 / inc
Cells(26, c.Column - 1).Value = mean14 / inc

End If

Next
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you would be using VBA to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Julien Marrec comment, you may want to get familiar with Array Formulas. Good starting point could be [Cheap Pearson intro to Array Formulas](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/arrayformulas.aspx).

In your case, you may want to use:

```
=AVERAGE(IF(E5:E26=TRUE,D5:D26))
=AVERAGE(IF(E5:E26=TRUE,C5:C26))
```

to calculate average of columns C and D respectively.

similarly:

```
=STDEV.P(IF(E5:E26=TRUE,D5:D26))
=MEDIAN(IF(E5:E26=TRUE,D5:D26))
```

Remember (quote from the link):

> ENTERING AN ARRAY FORMULA: To enter a formula as an array formula, type the formula in the cell and press the CTRL SHIFT and ENTER keys at the same time rather then just ENTER. You must do this the first time you enter the formula and whenever you edit the formula later. If you do this properly, Excel will display the formula enclosed in curly braces { }. You do not type in the braces -- Excel will display them automatically. If you neglect to enter the formula with CTRL SHIFT ENTER, the formula may return a #VALUE error or return an incorrect result.

Comment: Thanks, I am not familiar with array formulas. This really helped though!